# How to finetune a large pretrained NetModel?

Tags: neural-networks

Such an example is not in the docs so I'm posting this to clarify the process of finetuning. I'm looking for a minimal (but detailed) example of fine-tuning a pre-trained model with custom data (and best practices).

Here's a quick example with vgg and cifar:

```
obj = ResourceObject["CIFAR-10"];
trainingData = ResourceData[obj, "TrainingDataset"][[1]];
labels = Union @ Normal @ trainingData[[All, "Label"]];
targetDim = Length @ labels;

vgg = NetModel["VGG-16 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
trimmedNet = Take[vgg, {1, "fc7"}];

newNet = NetGraph[{trimmedNet, targetDim, Ramp, SoftmaxLayer[]},
  {NetPort["Image"] -> NetPort[1, "Input"], NetPort[1, "Output"] -> 2,
   2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NetPort["Label"]}, "Label" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", labels}]]

NetTrain[newNet, trainingData, 
 LearningRateMultipliers -> {2 -> 1, _ -> 0}]
```

The panel estimates the training time at over 2000 hours, so I'm sure this is not a smart or even correct way to do it.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTA]

Comment: I think your method is correct, however, VGG is trained on a different scale from CIFAR. I think that when networks are trained on CIFAR, the stem is modified to have smaller C1 kernel size.

Comment: I don't think the LearningRateMultipliers are working or being set properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different levels of transfer learning (fine tuning) applying to different cases (data size and data variations, etc.).

[image]

Generally speaking, there are four levels of transfer learning depending on the data size and similarity of the data:

1. If the size of the new data is large and the new data is very different from the original training data, we usually retrain the whole network from scratch on the new data.
2. If the size of the new data is large and is very similar to the original training data, we usually fine tune the network on the new data. We replace the last fully-connected layer with a randomly initialized layer matching the number of classes in the new data set and initialize the rest of the network with the pre-trained weights. Then we train the whole network on the new data.
3. If the size of the new data is small and very similar to the original data, we slice off the fully-connected layers at the end of the convolution layers, and attach a fully-connected layer with a randomly initialized layer matching the number of classes in the new data set. Then we freeze the pretrained parts of he network and train only the last fully-connected layers.
4. If the size of the new data is small and is very different from the original data, we slice off most of the pre-trained layers near the beginning of the network and add to the remaining pre-trained layers a new fully-connected layer that matches the number of classes in the new data set. We then train only the fully-connected layer with the weights of all other parts frozen.

### Example with MNIST

In this example, we train a network only on examples with numbers from 0-4, and retrain the classification head on examples with numbers from 5-9.

prepare the data

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];

trainingData1 = Select[trainingData, Values[#] <= 4 &];
testData1 = Select[testData, Values[#] <= 4 &];
trainingData2 = Select[trainingData, Values[#] >= 5 &];
testData2 = Select[testData, Values[#] >= 5 &];
```

train the net on examples of 0-4

```
lenet = NetChain[{
   ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
   ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
   FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, SoftmaxLayer[]},
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}],
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]
  ]

trained1 = 
 NetTrain[lenet, trainingData1, ValidationSet -> testData1, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 3];

ClassifierMeasurements[trained1, testData1, "Accuracy"]
(* 0.99747 *)
```

fine-tune the classification head on the new dataset, with the feature extraction part of the network been fixed

```
trained2 = 
 NetTrain[lenet, trainingData2, 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {8 ;; 10 -> 1, _ -> None}, 
  ValidationSet -> testData2, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]

ClassifierMeasurements[trained2, testData2, "Accuracy"]
(* 0.947542 *)
```

You can see more detailed explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141150/1364).

### Example with inception-V3

In this example, we apply transfer learning on inception-v3 and use it to classify five types of flowers. The flower dataset contains 3670 images of five types of flowers, and it can be downloaded from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz). Since the dataset is very small, we only retrain the final fully-connected layer of inception model.

```
inception = 
 NetModel["Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]
```

[image]

```
net = NetChain[{Take[inception, {1, "flatten"}], LinearLayer[5], 
   SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
  "Output" -> 
   NetDecoder[{"Class", {"daisy", "dandelion", "roses", "sunflowers", 
      "tulips"}}]]
dir = "~/Downloads/tf_files/flower_photos/";

loadFiles[dir_] := 
  Map[File[#] -> FileNameTake[#, {-2}] &, 
   FileNames["*.jpg", dir, Infinity]];

flowerData = loadFiles[dir];

trainingData = 
 RandomSample[flowerData, Round[0.9*Length[flowerData]]]; testData = 
 Complement[flowerData, trainingData];
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, trainingData, 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {2 ;; 3 -> 1, _ -> None}, 
  ValidationSet -> testData, MaxTrainingRounds -> 3, 
  TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

now test the model on flowers

```
test = List @@@ RandomSample[testData, 12];
testimg = test[[All, 1]];
lbPredic = trained /@ testimg;
lbGt = test[[All, 2]];
Grid@Partition[#, 
    4] &@(Labeled[#1, Column[{"   true:" <> #2, "predict:" <> #3}], 
     Top] & @@@ Transpose[{Import /@ testimg, lbPredic, lbGt}])
```

[image]

Test on the testData shows that the model has 91% accuracy.

```
testPred = trained[testData[[All, 1]]];
testGt = testData[[All, 2]];

#[True]/(#[True] + #[False]) &@
  Counts[#1 == #2 & @@@ Transpose[{testPred, testGt}]] // N
(* 0.912807 *)
```

Comment: Can you start the example from a pretrained NetModel please?

Comment: Lenet isn't realistic, and some issues arise with more complicated nets

Comment: I think there are examples like your answer already in the docs, I was hoping for an answer tackling a harder problem with mid level feature learning :(

Comment: @M.R. I don't have a computer powerful enough to train the pretrained networks. Sorry if this is not what you are looking for, I will remove the answer for now. But maybe you can say that in your question that you are looking for fine-tuning the mid layers. I'll have to fix the [GPU problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140580/1364) on my cluster before I can try any real world examples.

Comment: No, don't remove your answer, it's informative :) I'll give it a +1 anyway

Comment: @M.R. OK, thanks! I'll try to improve it as I get access to the GPU on cluster.

Comment: If you don't have a fast machine, I can show you how to train remotely if you'd like to chat

Comment: @M.R. I created a room "neural network", can you join in? I don't know how to invite people to chat rooms.